# How to use angular 2 tags in asp.net razor views like _layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add angular 2 tags like [routelink]='["/account/login"]' in my mvc razor layout.cshtml page, for navigate to this link act like angular 2 typescript link. I want link like this

```
<a [routelink]='["/account/login"]'><i class="fa fa-power-on"></i> Log In</a>
```

and it should be behavior like angular 2 link. but it's not working even not clickable. So, what have to do in asp.net mvc with angular 2 application to approach this state to apply angular tags in razor views

Comment: Is there any solution regarding this problem.?